# Redhat 8 Display Issue

Tags: display, rhel8

I am running a vncserver on host1 in display 1
echo $DISPLAY host1:1

Now I want to through the display from host2 to host 1 but I am getting some error. I tried gvim for this and getting the following error:

E233: cannot open displayE852: The child process failed to start the GUI

Same for few other applications as well. Like for firefox I am getting:

Failed to open connection to "session" message bus: /usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

I did "xhost +" on host1 and "setenv DISPLAY host1:1" on host2 as well but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we need to start the vncserver with "-listen tcp" option.

vncserver -listen tcp

This seems to be RHEL8 specific issue.